# Dynamically include header as a component in StackNavigator RootScreen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to have a custom header above my navigation tabs. I have a component for the header that I include in the RootScreen but I have no way of dynamically showing/hiding this as far as I've found.

```
const tabBarLabelAndNotifications = (notifications, stack) => {
  return (
    <View style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      <Text style={{color: '#3F92DF', fontSize: 10, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{stack}</Text>
      <View style={styles.circle}>
        <Text style={[styles.notifications, styles.fontLatoBold]}>{notifications}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

const EngagementStack = createStackNavigator({
  Engagements: EngagementsScreen,
});

EngagementStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'ENGAGEMENTS',
};

const QueryStack = createStackNavigator({
  Queries: QueriesScreen,
});

QueryStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: tabBarLabelAndNotifications(4, 'QUERY')
};

const IssuesStack = createStackNavigator({
  Issues: IssuesScreen,
});

IssuesStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: tabBarLabelAndNotifications(2, 'ISSUES')
};

const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  EngagementStack,
  QueryStack,
  IssuesStack
},
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      style: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
      },
      labelStyle: {
        color: '#3F92DF',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 10
      },
      indicatorStyle: {
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(82, 170, 231, 0.2)',
        borderRadius: 4
      }
    }
  }
);

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: TabNavigator
    },
    EngagementDetailModal: {
      screen: EngagementDetailModal
    },
    RequestForRecordsModal: {
      screen: RequestForRecordsModal
    }
  },
  {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
)

const RootNav = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default function RootScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Header />
      <RootNav />
    </View>
  );
}
```

from the code above, I want to dynamically show the `<Header />` component as long as I am on a page and not a modal.

I've tried using withNavigation within the same file as the code I've posted but checking the navigation prop just gives me undefined. The code never seems to re-render from the root. I've tried adding navigationOptions per individual page but it's not rendering my custom header.

**EDIT 1**: per the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html#replacing-the-title-with-a-custom-component). The following code only shows an empty white space above the tabs in my view

```
static navigationOptions = {
    // headerTitle instead of title
    headerTitle: <Header />,
  };
```

And the component that is being imported just to test

```
export default function Header() {
    return (
        <View><Text>hi</Text></View>
    )
}
```

[image: The outcome]

Answer (score 0):

Inside the screen where you want to hide/show the modal static navigation options:

```
   static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { state } = navigation;
    let header = <CustomHeader />;
    if (state.params) header = state.params.modalShowing ? null : <CustomHeader />
    return { header }
}
```

Then, when you want to show the modal do a setParams:

```
this.props.navigation.setParams({modalShowing:!this.state.showModal})
```

Comment: Even when just trying to use navigationOptions within the page that I want to show the custom header, nothing appears. Per the documentation I should do something like `static navigationOptions = { headerTitle: <CustomHeader /> }` which still does not show a header, it just shows an empty white block

Comment: DId you try my solution? It's the same i use to hide/show the header and it works smoothly

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, tintColor }) => {

    return {
      headerTitle: (
        <Header />
      ),
      headerLeft: (
        <View />
      ),
      headerRight: (
       <View />
      )
    };
  };
```

Comment: Even this just shows an empty white space above my tabs. I'm starting to wonder if this isn't something else causing it.. No matter what i try, I can't get anything to appear.

Comment: could you create snack for this.